# how to make Powershell save all of the hashes to a text file and save it on my desktop?

Tags: powershell

im using this script below to find the hashes of my media video files 
what I want is a text file with all of the hashes on my desktop or on my whatever place I want
can you please edit this powershell script to me ?

`Get-ChildItem "path of source" -Recurse | Get-FileHash`

also a secondry question if mods allow it
does hashing files using the script above 100% safe 
is there is a chance of files getting corrupted as a side effect of hashing ?

Comment: To add text (hashes) to a file you can use `Out-File`.

Comment: Have you tried using `Get-ChildItem "path of source" -Recurse | Get-FileHash > hashes.txt` and `>> hashes.txt` for the rest?